# upload an new android app in Play Store to download another app

Tags: android, upload, policy

i want upload app to download other app in outside of play stor cuase the policy and privacy are not accepte this app for live channels like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upload your app apk to your server or any file hosting service. When download is click, download this apk.

Comment: i mean if google allow this app ..?? what abut term of service??

Comment: There is a high chance google will find out. Like @Gabe Sechan suggested, it's better to use a website instead. This is what apps like PokerStar do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be banned as soon as Google finds out.  That's against their terms of service.  You can make the app downloadable from your website, but Google Play apps can't directly download other programs.

Comment: and can you please give me a soulition